# presentViewController:imagePickerController is popping my navigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using presentViewController:imagePickerController to display the UIImagePickerController. For some reason when I end up dismissing that controller my original navigation controller looses it's stack and my application is back at the root view controller.

I am logging self.navigationController.viewControllers and I can see that after I run the presentViewController:imagePickerController line my navigation controller looses all of its controllers except for the root controller.

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
 imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
 imagePickerController.delegate = self;
 imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

 self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;

DLog(@"self.navigationController:%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
[self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{
        DLog(@" after presenting self.navigationController:%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);

    }];
```

////Closing it

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    DLog(@"self.navigationController:%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

/////Where my NC is set up

```
OFMainViewController *mainController = [[OFMainViewController alloc]init];
    mainController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: Is anything acting as the delegate of the nav controller? Do you explicitly change the nav stack anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using self.navigationController use self for both dismissing and calling the imagepickerviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You should present `imagePickeController` on `self` instead of `self.navigationController`.

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{
    DLog(@" after presenting self:%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);

}];
```

And dissmiss it accordingly:

```
////Closing it

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    DLog(@"self.navigationController:%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```